# C# WCF Client error

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I'm trying to call a WCF web service function to send data and I receive bellow exceptions

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at sgsGemma.WUI.WebServiceOnDemand.WebService.IDataSync.UpdateProductCategoryAssociations(String ProductId, String Outline, Boolean isFirstCall)
   at sgsGemma.WUI.WebServiceOnDemand.WebService.DataSyncClient.UpdateProductCategoryAssociations(String ProductId, String Outline, Boolean isFirstCall) in C:\antg\Addins\Gemma\Baseline\Sources\WinForms\sgsGemma.WUI.WebServiceOnDemand\sgsGemma.WUI.WebServiceOnDemand\Service References\WebService\Reference.cs:line 150
   at sgsGemma.WUI.WebServiceOnDemand.sgsgmWebServiceOnDemandF.SendItemCategoryAssociationsToWebService() in C:\antg\Addins\Gemma\Baseline\Sources\WinForms\sgsGemma.WUI.WebServiceOnDemand\sgsGemma.WUI.WebServiceOnDemand\sgsgmWebServiceOnDemandF.cs:line 704
15:29:32.80 Th1 Error sgsGemma.WUI.WebServiceOnDemand.sgsgmWebServiceOnDemandF SendItemCategoryAssociationsToWebService System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at sgsGemma.WUI.WebServiceOnDemand.WebService.IDataSync.UpdateProductCategoryAssociations(String ProductId, String Outline, Boolean isFirstCall)
   at sgsGemma.WUI.WebServiceOnDemand.WebService.DataSyncClient.UpdateProductCategoryAssociations(String ProductId, String Outline, Boolean isFirstCall) in C:\antg\Addins\Gemma\Baseline\Sources\WinForms\sgsGemma.WUI.WebServiceOnDemand\sgsGemma.WUI.WebServiceOnDemand\Service References\WebService\Reference.cs:line 150
   at sgsGemma.WUI.WebServiceOnDemand.sgsgmWebServiceOnDemandF.SendItemCategoryAssociationsToWebService() in C:\antg\Addins\Gemma\Baseline\Sources\WinForms\sgsGemma.WUI.WebServiceOnDemand\sgsGemma.WUI.WebServiceOnDemand\sgsgmWebServiceOnDemandF.cs:line 704
```

I called in same application and same form an other function of same web service and it works fine. But this one not.

Can anyone please explain to me what means this exception and how can fix it? 
Thank you

Comment: Did you try turning on the trace and logs as suggested in the error message and looking for the problem?

Comment: I havnt access to the trace and logs

Comment: This says it all: _The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error._ The error is on the side of the server. Consult the service API what exceptions can occur and/or consult the owner of the service.

Answer (score 2):

There is some exception on the webservice side. 
Either debug the webservice method or set IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true in the webservice config file.

Comment: Yes you are right. Finaly I found the solutions it was an exception from Server side